# prevent username from getting cache in django and memcache

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I am using per-view based caching in Django and I am using Memcached as caching backend in my system. It's caching working fine but the problem I stuck with is, memcache is caching everything including username. So, I want to exclude username from getting cache. I have tried template fragment caching and two phased method recommended by Holovaty but none of them worked fine for me. So, I was wondering what approach does people use to exclude username from getting cache along with entire view in per-view based caching. Thanks in Advance. I would appreciate if working snippet of code can be provided. Thanks Again.